# PHP: multiple selection in Wordpress function

Tags: wordpress

I have a simple PHP WordPress script that may allow a role called `Shop manager` to edit roles that I select.

I have this code:

```
function myextension_shop_manager_role_edit_capabilities( $roles ) {
    $roles[] = 'wcwp_a';
    return $roles;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_shop_manager_editable_roles', 'myextension_shop_manager_role_edit_capabilities' );
```

Now I need to add to `$roles[] = 'wcwp_a';` another value like is there `'wcwp_a'`.

I already tried this but it's not working:

```
function myextension_shop_manager_role_edit_capabilities( $roles ) {
    $roles[] = ['wcwp_a', 'wcwp_b'];
    return $roles;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_shop_manager_editable_roles', 'myextension_shop_manager_role_edit_capabilities' );
```

So is there any option on how I can add there another value for example `'wcwp_b'`?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and works.

```
function myextension_shop_manager_role_edit_capabilities( $roles ) {
     
    return array($roles[] = 'wcwp_a', $roles[] = 'wcwp_b', $roles[] = 'wcwp_c', $roles[] = 'wcwp_d');
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_shop_manager_editable_roles', 'myextension_shop_manager_role_edit_capabilities' );
```